# ldapmodify can't contact LDAP server for cn=config

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

I've been pulling my hair out for 3 days now trying to configure ldap.  I first tried installing from source but then reinstalled using `apt-get`, which caused some migration errors, but I believe those are all resolved.  I am able to execute `ldapsearch -x` and its cousins when I properly specify a root DN (for some reason the base specified `ldap.conf` isn't working), which I assume indicates that the server is functioning properly; I have as well verified that the server is listening below.  However, I'm trying to set up SSL, and I understand that with the version i installed through apt-get needs to be configured in `cn=config`, and therefore must use the `-H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL` options below, however it is unable to contact the server when I try.

```
root@aeneas:/tmp/ldap# ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -D 'cn=config' -f ./modify.ldif
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

root@aeneas:/tmp/ldap# netstat -plane | grep slapd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          53158       11280/slapd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:636             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          53163       11280/slapd     
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          53159       11280/slapd     
tcp6       0      0 :::636                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          53164       11280/slapd     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     53160    11280/slapd         /var/run/slapd/ldapi
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    53154    11280/slapd 

root@aeneas:/tmp/ldap# cat ./modify.ldif 
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/cacert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/servercrt.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/lda/pssl/serverkey.pem
```

I later disabled `ldaps:///` listening on port 636, suspecting that `ldapmodify` was contacting the SSL server by default then quitting when not given a certificate, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, there were some executables left over in `/usr/local/` from the original from-source install; removing these fixed the connectivity issue.  The LDIF is causing problems, but that is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The `slapi` connection to `LDAP` is based on the presence of a pipe file on the filesystem to bind client and server toghether.

Of course the location of the pipe file is installation-dependent.

If the server is compiled, let's say in `/usr/local`, the slapd server binds to the pipe in:

```
/usr/local/lib/run/ldapi
```

On the other hand, the `ldapsearch` stock tool installed from apt (Debian example), looks for a pipe file in:

```
/var/run/slapd/ldapi
```

I would recommend creating a soft link.